# Passing data with array but shows as empty in table view delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4, nsarray

My app is based on a `UISplitViewController` and it's a Universal app.
I have this code in my app which does work looking up data from webserver.

The result shows a count of 100 but the `NSMutableArray` is `nil` after `[myTable reloadData]`.

How can I solve it?

**Scenario**
Page1: a search engine, will pass value to another view
Page2: receive value from [Page1] then pass to instance `sendData`. Get result by JSON then convert them to `NSMutableArray', using this`NSMutableArray`to populate`UITableView' after `viewdidload`

Code:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        NSLog(@"ConfigureView");
        [self sendData];
        [self refreshTable];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewdidload");
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) refreshTable 
{
    NSLog(@"Refresh Table");
    [myTable reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Counter:%i",allFilteredItemsArray.count);
}

#pragma mark - Table

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %i", allFilteredItemsArray.count);
    return [allFilteredItemsArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"fileredCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    HardwareCell *hardwareCell = [[HardwareCell alloc] init];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *item = [allFilteredItemsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    hardwareCell.lbl_model = [item objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;

}

#pragma mark - Searching Asset

-(void)sendData
{    
    NSString *searchString = [self.detailItem description];

    .........ignored some of the code............

    allFilteredItemsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Search Count: %i", allFilteredItemsArray.count);
    NSLog(@"End Searching Data.");

}
```

Result:

```
2012-10-17 10:45:54.535 Portal[10753:c07] viewdidload
2012-10-17 10:45:54.536 Portal[10753:c07] Value to be sent: %/%/%/%/%/1
2012-10-17 10:45:54.537 Portal[10753:c07] ConfigureView
2012-10-17 10:45:54.537 Portal[10753:c07] Start Seraching Data...
2012-10-17 10:45:54.923 Portal[10753:c07] Search Count: 100
2012-10-17 10:45:54.923 Portal[10753:c07] End Searching Data.
2012-10-17 10:45:54.923 Portal[10753:c07] Refresh Table
2012-10-17 10:45:54.924 Portal[10753:c07] Counter:100
2012-10-17 10:45:54.924 Portal[10753:c07] numberOfRowsInSection: 0
```

Comment: We're missing key information here.  Where is `allFilteredItemsArray` declared and where is it instantiated?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allFilteredItemsArray;` was declared, `@synthesize` in .h file, init/alloc it `viewDidLoad` in .m file.

Comment: ARC/non-ARC?  You refer to a declared property `allFilteredItemsArray` while in the implementation you are not using the property `self.allFilteredItemsArray`

Comment: That should be ARC. XCode default, I didn't change anything in preference. So what should I do the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should access allFilteredItemsArray as self.allFilteredItemsArray that might resolve the problem ;-)

Comment: I put `self.allFilteredItemsArray` inside `NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %i", allFilteredItemsArray.count)`. It seems did not work.

Comment: it should be NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %i",[self.allFilteredItemsArray count]);

Comment: call refreshTable method after some delay with performSelector: afterDelay: or after receiving the response data means you should call refreshTable in sendData method instead in configureView.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alloc your array compulsorily though it's class-level object. Alloc allFilteredItemsArray in viewdidload & write it as self.allFilteredItemsArray. Check the following code:

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

self.allFilteredItemsArray=tempArray;

[tempArray release];

NSLog(@"viewdidload");

[self configureView];

}

Also You can use %d for array count as follow:

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %d",[allFilteredItemsArray count]);

return [allFilteredItemsArray count];

}

Answer (score 0):

If `allFilteredItemsArray` is a property of your subclass, you should refer to it as `[self allFilteredItemsArray]`.